# Encoding data in joomla 1.0.0

Tags: joomla

I'm writing a tool to migrate data from excel to joomla
    1.0.0 db.

My data have Vietnamese character

> (Ex: "Thành Phố Hồ Chí Minh").

When migarted, data show in page is error

> ("Th?nh Ph? H? Ch? Minh").

I think joomla encoded data before saving to db but i dont know what's encoding code?.
How can do that?
Thanks

Comment: Please add only tags which matches your question. Since you said, that you're using version 1.0.0, you should add tags for different joomla versions.

Comment: Why on earth are you still using Joomla 1.0.0? You do realise it's about 10 years old

Comment: Yeap, my application is 10 years old and now i need maintenance this app :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching google many times, i finded answer for my question

```
This encoding is latin1
```

use sql command below to convert data before saving

```
convert(cast(convert(name using  latin1) as binary) using utf8)
```